# Add .bat file extension back

Tags: windows-10, batch

I managed to delete the .bat file extension in windows 10. In other words, removed the file type association of .bat, so now all batch files do not open correctly systemwide.
How can I add it back and have it be executable rather than associated with an app?

Comment: The existing answers are assuming you deleted the file extension on a single file; I understood your question that you removed the file type association of .bat, so now all batch files do not open correctly systemwide. Can you please edit your question to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the Start menu. Type `folder options`
2. A dialog box with the title "Folder Options" will appear.
3. Click to uncheck the box for "Hide extensions for known file types".
4. Click on Ok. Where you can see the extension of all files.
5. Go to the file. Right click rename it.
6. Add .bat extension. Remove if any extension
7. It prompts message asking functioning may click on yes.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the following code by pasting it into Notepad, saving it as a `.reg` file and merging it with admin privileges to restore your default file type association:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; http://www.tenforums.com
; Tutorial: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-default-file-type-associations-restore-windows-10-a.html


[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat]
@="batfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile]
@="Windows Batch File"
"EditFlags"=hex:30,04,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,61,00,63,00,70,00,70,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,36,00,30,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6d,00,\
  61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,36,\
  00,38,00,00,00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,\
  00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,2f,00,70,00,20,\
  00,25,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,63,00,6d,00,\
  64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2f,00,43,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,\
  00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shellex\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}]
@="{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.bat]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\FileExts\.bat]
```

You can also download the same code within a readily available `.reg` file from original source below...

(Source:  [Restore Default File Type Associations in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-restore-default-file-type-associations-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: Yes, that worked Thanks. don't know/remember  how to mark the question as answered

Comment: Always glad to help!  [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Ah, I was probably thinking of another Q&A site!